# How to get post parameters from http request in lua sent to NodeMCU

Tags: http, post, lua, nodemcu

I sent this HTTP POST request via Tasker (Android app) to my NodeMCU, which looks like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Tasker/4.9u4m (Android/6.0.1)
Connection: close
Content-Length: 10
Host: 192.168.0.22
Accept-Encoding: gzip

<action>Play</action><SetVolume>5</SetVolume>
```

I only want to extract what is between the "<action>" and "<SetVolume>" parameters. How can I do that?

Comment: [My first solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42044546/6879826) to your other question may be able to help here. Exactly what output do you expect?

Comment: Yup, your answer solved my problem, I thought that maybe rephrasing my question would help for simplicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here is another solution I came up with:

```
string.gsub(request, "<(%a+)>([^<]+)</%a+>", function(key, val)
  print(key .. ": " .. val)
end)
```

A working example using the given HTTP request in your question can be seen here:

https://repl.it/repls/GlamorousAnnualConferences

Answer (score 1):

This function allows you to extract text from between two string delimiters:

```
function get_text (str, init, term)
   local _, start = string.find(str, init)
   local stop = string.find(str, term)
   local result = nil
   if _ and stop then
      result = string.sub(str, start + 1, stop - 1)
   end
   return result
end
```

Sample interaction:

```
> msg = "<action>Play</action><SetVolume>5</SetVolume>"
> get_text(msg, "<action>", "<SetVolume>")
Play</action>
> get_text(msg, "<action>", "</SetVolume>")
Play</action><SetVolume>5
```

This is a modification of the above function that allows `nil` for either of the parameters `init` or `term`. If `init` is `nil`, then text is extracted up to the `term` delimiter. If `term` is `nil`, then text is extracted from after `init` to the end of the string.

```
function get_text (str, init, term)
   local _, start
   local stop = (term and string.find(str, term)) or 0
   local result = nil
   if init then
      _, start = string.find(str, init)
   else
      _, start = 1, 0
   end

   if _ and stop then
      result = string.sub(str, start + 1, stop - 1)
   end
   return result
end
```

Sample interaction:

```
> msg = "<action>Play</action><SetVolume>5</SetVolume>"
> get_text(msg)
<action>Play</action><SetVolume>5</SetVolume>
> get_text(msg, nil, '<SetVolume>')
<action>Play</action>
> get_text(msg, '</action>')
<SetVolume>5</SetVolume>
> get_text(msg, '<action>', '<SetVolume>')
Play</action>
```